# Slot Content Distribution of Table Component using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a table component that distribute styling columns through `colgroup` and `col` tags and let who use the component can override how `tbody` content rendered. I use `named slot` in Vuejs but It dose not work (the **colgroup** and **table body content** slot seem not to replace with the user's content) here the code.

#### HTML

```
<body>

  <div id='app'>
    <simple-table>
      <colgroup slot='colstyle'>
        <col style='background-color: yellow;'>
      </colgroup>
      <h2 slot='above-table'>
    Above Table Content Modified
    </h2>
      <tbody slot='tbody-content'>
        <tr>
          <td>override 1</td>
          <td>override 2</td>
          <td>override 3</td>
          <tr>
      </tbody>
    </simple-table>
  </div>


  <script id='simple-table' type='x-template'>
    <slot name='above-table'>
      Default Above Table Content
    </slot>
    <table>
      <slot name='colstyle'>
        <colgroup>
          <col span='2' style='background-color: red;'>
        </colgroup>
      </slot>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First</th>
          <th>Second</th>
          <th>Third</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <slot name='tbody-content'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>yyy</td>
            <td>zzz</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </slot>
    </table>
  </script>
</body>
```

#### Javascript

```
Vue.component('simple-table', {
  template: '#simple-table'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "body"
});
```

[on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1eq1369/)

Is there any better solution for this.
Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is how html works. In [Vuejs guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#is_attribute), says that

> Some HTML elements, for example `<table>`, has restrictions on what
>   elements can appear inside it

That's why they created the special `is` attribute. But notice that in your case, you can't use

```
    <colgroup is='colstyle'>
      <col span='2' style='background-color: red;'>
    </colgroup>
```

Because **`colstyle`** is the name of a slot, not a custom component. So what I would do would be create small custom components for those slots, and add them through the `is` attribute

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice the Vuejs guide. finally I got some workaround by your answer. `colgroup` also work https://jsfiddle.net/0xgj83up/ . if these cloud be done using slot. It'd be more clean and simple IMHO.